# Azure - AKS Blueprints

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-blueprints

I know that Azure supports Blueprints for AKS however I don't find any sample Blueprints for AKS.

Is there any Azure - AKS Blueprints available publicly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bluenprints are pretty much arm templates. there are bunch of arm template examples for AKS available on the web, for example in the official examples repo:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

you can probably find more on the AKS docs